# Android post data to mysql through PHP script

Tags: android, mysql

i m new to android development. i am trying to insert data into remote Mysql database through php script using android's HttpPost. i have added the permission for internet. i am getting forced closed error. My code is below:

```
   package com.regsiteration.regfi;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class Main extends Activity {


    public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xyz.com/folder/register.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "demo@ats.in"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "robin hood"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234590"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //postData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Please tell me what i am missing or doing wrong. Thanks in advance. Here is my logcat trace

```
08-17 20:16:49.530: I/dalvikvm(630): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-17 20:16:49.654: I/dalvikvm(630): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-17 20:16:49.779: D/AndroidRuntime(630): Shutting down VM
08-17 20:16:49.779: W/dalvikvm(630): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.regsiteration.regfi/com.regsiteration.regfi.Main}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.regsiteration.regfi.Main.postData(Main.java:37)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at com.regsiteration.regfi.Main.onCreate(Main.java:50)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-17 20:16:49.799: E/AndroidRuntime(630):  ... 11 more
08-17 20:16:49.960: I/dalvikvm(630): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-17 20:16:49.970: I/dalvikvm(630): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-17 20:16:50.340: I/dalvikvm(630): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-17 20:16:50.350: I/dalvikvm(630): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Can you paste your logcat output?

Comment: i have added the logcat trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This is your error. Network stuff can't be done on the UI thread in newer SDK versions. 
You can "override" this with

```
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Hey Ascorbin, thanks for the answer. Actually i am new to android development. Can u please tell me where to write the code suggested by you in my code.

Comment: Just put it in the onCreate() Method of your activity.

Comment: Hey Ascorbin, Thanks it worked. but i think this will not work below SDK level 9. so is it advisable to use this method?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, perhaps someone else can clarify it: 
Your App has a minimum and target SDK level. Since this works, your minimum SDK level is set to 9 or higher. Else Eclipse would tell you that it doesnt know StrictMode. 
If you want your app to run on devices below SDK 9, you set the minimum SDK level to below 9, and then this "workaround" should not even be necessary, your code ill work as you posted it in your question. 
If you want to learn something useful, do what your initial error suggested and dont do networking on the UI, but in an own thread.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Ascorbin

Comment: `AsyncTask` is another great option since API 3. ["AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

the constructor of the class HTTPPost take an Uri object

So try this:

```
URI url = new URI("http://xyz.com/folder/register.php");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
```

[sources](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html#HttpPost%28java.lang.String%29)